# Calling JQuery .load after html redirect

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, redirect

I am writing an application that I want to make more user friendly by removing the amount of clicks needed to navigate.
At the moment pages are loaded like so:

```
<a class='pageloader' name='page1.html'>Page 1</a>

<script>
    $('.pageloader').click(function(){
        // Load the page that the user clicked on by taking the name property and appending it to includes/
        $('.content').load("pages/" + this.name);
    });
</script>
```

Basicly this takes the name of the clicked link and replaces the content div's content with whatever is inside the file that matches the name property.

Now my only problem is that I can't redirect people to pages using HTML because the only page that has proper styling is index.php.
Obviously I am now redirecting people to index.php after an action is finished, but I would like to redirect them to a specific page.

I've thought about calling

```
$('.content').load('pages/edit-plein.php');
```

(This code is inside a .php script that writes to a file)

But that only gives me an error since it cannot find the .content div.

Would anyone know a good method to redirect a user to the page I want?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand you want to make shure the right content gets loaded (inside that div) when you share the link to a specific subpage on your site, but can only share a link of your index.php because of its styling.

I would suggest you add a variable to your URL, i.e. like

```
index.php?page=edit-plein
```

then get that var with PHP and create a JS call to your pageloader, like this:

```
<?php
if ( $_GET['page'] != '' ) {
    echo '<script>$(".content").load("pages/'. $_GET['page'] .'");</script>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good way for links:

```
<a class='pageloader' name='page1.html'>Page 1</a>
```

Maybe you can try this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="pageloader" id="page1">Page 1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="pageloader" id="page2">Page 2</a>
```

And JS must be like this:

```
$('.pageloader').click(function(){
  $('.content').load("pages/" + $(this).attr('id') + ".html");
});
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Not at all. I wanted to know of a good way to redirect to my index with a certain file included, not this.